# Script to import .bib and output HTML based on a style

Tags: bibtex, automation, scripts

I'm able to use various tools (such as pyP2B.py) to generate a BibTex database.   I've also successfully created a AMA styled RTF of the database using JabRef and the APAish extension, although this has to be done manually - and the output is RTF, not HTML or PDF.

What I'm ultimately working toward is automating this process for use in a web application.  I'd like to pass the bib file and style as arguments, and receive a stylized PDF or HTML as an output string.

---

*postnote - if my question is not suited for TEX, please go easy.  I had an unexpectedly negative response to a similar question posted on StackOverflow yesterday which was more open ended than this.  If needed let me know, and I'll delete - please do not punish with downrates.*

Comment: Perhaps try a `LaTeX` source file with `\bibliographystyle{foo}` and `\bibliography{bar}` and have your script rename the generated style and `.bib` files appropriately? `pdflatex` will generate pdf; there are several `tex2html` options.

Comment: Maybe [bib2xhtml](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bib2xhtml) or [bib2html](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibhtml) can help you?